# list only files which contain one specific character only, when not specified amount repeated

Tags: linux, bash

how do I simply list all the files which contain one specific character while not knowing the length of a file name. For example if I have files with name starting from test0 ending with test10000 and I want to list all the files which only contain number 9. result should be test9, test99, test999, test9999.

currently my code looks like this  `ls test{9,99,999,9999}` which is very static, and i am looking for more dynamic one.

Comment: you want all files that contain a `9` (and possibly other numbers, too)? you want all files that contain **just** the number `9`?

Comment: @markp-fuso only 9 in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution using `ls`:

```
$ ls -1
file.ycz.99.88.txt                 # not a match
file.ycz.99.txt                    # match
file09.txt                         # not a match
file9.txt                          # match
file993.txt                        # not a match

$ ls -1I "*[0-8]*"                 # '-I' says to ignore files that match the pattern
file.ycz.99.txt
file9.txt
```

**NOTE**: I added the '-1' to place each file on a separate line solely for readability purposes of this answer

---

To make it a bit more dynamic, though a bit verbose:

```
$ ignore='[0123456789]'
$ keep='9'
$ ls -1I "*${ignore//${keep}}*"     # '${ignore//${keep}}' strip '9' from the 'ignore' variable leaving us with 'ls "*[012345678]*"
file.ycz.99.txt
file9.txt
```

To see the expansions in play:

```
$ set -xv
$ ls -1I "*${ignore//${keep}}*"
+ ls -1I '*[012345678]*'
file.ycz.99.txt
file9.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\./[^0-9]*9*'
```

Comment: it gives a correct output, but is there no more simple way to do it? without using regex and using ls command instead.

Comment: @Saba : You can not describe _repeat an arbitrary number of occurances of some pattern_ using just globbing. You need regular expressions for this, or invert the logic (as in the answer of markp-fuso). The "globbing"- pattern language is simply not expressive enought for this job.